# Error compiling with cordova-plugin-qrscanner: Problem with 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

After installing cordova-plugin-qrscanner, I get the following error during compilation

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyApp'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

My specifications are as follows:

```
Using Java 11
Ionic CLI version 6.4.0
Cordova version 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with a plugin. Error means that there is no "implementation" method in build.gradle. I've looked to plugin which You provided:

https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/blob/master/src/android/qrscanner.gradle

In this file there is code

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

This plugin was not updated for 4 years so it's implementation is little bit deprecated. I've made some changes in this plugin to make this work.
https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/compare/master...Cubaza:cordova-plugin-qrscanner:master
As You can see, I've changed two files. In gradle file there is remove of `jcenter` repository (it's not working), ale change `compile` -> `implementation` method. Error which You facing is saying that there is no implementation method.
I need to change also appcompat to androidx package. Newest cordova using androix instead od compat packages.

But I don't think this plugin is good. I've checked on Samsung S21 and I can't get it working to show me scan window. Maybe other plugin will work.